# Run ExUnit.Case functions serially using Agent

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

I know that, by default, a ExUnit.Case is synchronous (according to [the ExUnit.Case docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html)).
I also read this issue ( https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/3580 ) and it seems test functions inside a Case are run serially.

When I run a simple test case without global state cases are indeed run serially.

But when I use global state with Agent the order of execution depends on luck. For the same call to

```
mix test --trace
```

the order of execution change. Here is my test suite:

```
defmodule SerialTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "1" do
    Agent.update(:card_id, fn nil -> 1 end)
    assert true
  end

  test "2" do
    res = Agent.get(:card_id, fn res -> res end)
    assert res == 1
  end

  test "3" do
    Agent.update(:card_id, fn id -> 3 end)
    assert true
  end

  test "4" do
    res = Agent.get(:card_id, fn res -> res end)
    assert res == 3
  end
end
```

Sometimes passes sometimes not.
How can I have the execution order of my functions be conform to the declaration order in the file where they are defined using Agent's global state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tests run serially but they run in **random order**. Your tests are failing because they are order dependent as they change some global state.

When you run your suite you see this at the bottom:

```
Randomized with seed 596046
```

You can disable it by adding `ExUnit.configure seed: 0` to your `test_helper.exs` but I would rather advise for your tests to be order independent.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the test cases run in the order they were defined by using the `seed` flag.

`--seed 0 --trace`